# Role seeking believes that said members have said role when they do not

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

```js
const { Discord, MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");
module.exports = {
    name: "ban",
    description: "bans user from guild",
    execute(client, message, cmd, args, Discord) {
        const member = message.mentions.users.first();
        const user = message.mentions.members.first();
        let admin = message.author.username;
        let server = message.guild.name;
        const memberTarget = message.guild.members.cache.get(member.id);
        let reason = args.join(" ").slice(22);
        if (!reason) reason = "No reason provided";

        const embed = new MessageEmbed().setDescription("`Please remember to mention the user **(Members, UserID)**`").setColor("YELLOW");

        const embed1 = new MessageEmbed().setDescription("You dont have enough permissions to execute this command!").setColor("RED");

        const embed2 = new MessageEmbed().setDescription("`Sorry But this User is not Bannable`").setColor("RED");

        const embed4 = new MessageEmbed().setTitle(`You have been banned from ${server}!`).setThumbnail(`${message.guild.iconURL()}`).addField("Reason:", `${reason}`).setFooter(`you were banned by ${admin}`).setTimestamp().setColor("RED");

        const embed5 = new MessageEmbed().setDescription(`**${admin}**, You Cannot Ban Yourself`);

        if (user.id === message.author.id) {
            message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed5] });
        }
        if (
            message.member.roles.cache.some((role) => role.name === "Administrator") ||
            message.member.roles.cache.some((role) => role.name === "Admin") ||
            message.member.roles.cache.some((role) => role.name === "Moderator") ||
            message.member.roles.cache.some((role) => role.name === "Mod")
        ) {
            message.channel.send(`Sorry I cannot ban Admins/Mods`);
        } else {
            if (!message.mentions.users.first()) return message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed] });
            if (!message.member.permissions.has("KICK_MEMBERS")) return message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed1] });
            if (!user.kickable) return message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed2] });

            if (!!message.mentions.users.first() && message.member.permissions.has("KICK_MEMBERS")) {
                const embed3 = new MessageEmbed()
                    .setColor("BLACK")
                    .setThumbnail(message.mentions.users.first().displayAvatarURL())
                    .setDescription(`<@${memberTarget.user.id}> has been banned!`)
                    .addField("Reason", `${reason}`)
                    .setFooter(`Banned by ${admin}`)
                    .setTimestamp();

                user.send({ embeds: [embed4] });
                setTimeout(function () {
                    user.ban()
                        .catch((err) => console.log(err))
                        .then(() => {
                            message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed3] });
                            message.channel.bulkDelete(1);
                        }, 20000);
                });
            }
        }
    },
};
```

So I'm seeking a way to get my bot not to ban Admin or Mod roles, however, the current way I have it set up it believes every member has said roles.

I'm looking to see if there is a better way to seek roles or if I have to move stuff around.

Help would really be appreciated as I'm trying my hardest to get this patched ASAP. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `if (message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'Administrator') || message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'Admin') || message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'Moderator') || message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'Mod'))` is not a good way for detecting if a person has a role...

Comment: What I mean by my previous comment is that, you should detect if they have like ADMINISTRATOR permissions or MANAGE_MESSAGES or possibly KICK_MEMBERS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const { Discord, MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js")
module.exports = {
    name: 'ban',
     description: "bans user from guild",
     execute(client, message, cmd, args, Discord){
    const member = message.mentions.users.first();
    const user = message.mentions.members.first();
    let admin = message.author.username;
    let server = message.guild.name;

    let reason = args.join(" ").slice(22);
    if(!reason) reason = "No reason provided";

    const embed = new MessageEmbed()
    .setDescription("`Please remember to mention the user **(Members, UserID)**`")
    .setColor("YELLOW")

    const embed1 = new MessageEmbed()
    .setDescription("You dont have enough permissions to execute this command!")
    .setColor("RED")

    const embed2 = new MessageEmbed()
    .setDescription("`Sorry But this User is not Bannable`")
    .setColor("RED")


    const embed4 = new MessageEmbed()

    .setTitle(`You have been banned from ${server}!`)
    .setThumbnail(`${message.guild.iconURL()}`)
    .addField('Reason:', `${reason}`)
    .setFooter(`you were banned by ${admin}`)
    .setTimestamp()
    .setColor('RED')

    const embed5 = new MessageEmbed()

    .setDescription(`**${admin}**, You Cannot Ban Yourself`)

if(!message.member.permissions.has('KICK_MEMBERS')) return message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed1] })
if(!message.mentions.users.first()) return message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed] })

    if(user.id === message.author.id){
      message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed5] })
    } else if (user.roles.cache.some(role => ['Administrator', 'Admin', 'Moderator', 'Mod'].includes(role.name))){
          message.channel.send(`Sorry I cannot ban Admins/Mods`)
    } else {


        if(!user.kickable) return message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed2] })

        if(!!message.mentions.users.first() && message.member.permissions.has('BAN_MEMBERS')) {
          const memberTarget = message.guild.members.cache.get(member.id)
          const embed3 = new MessageEmbed()
          .setColor("BLACK")
          .setThumbnail(message.mentions.users.first().displayAvatarURL())
          .setDescription(`<@${memberTarget.user.id}> has been banned!`)
          .addField('Reason', `${reason}` )
          .setFooter(`Banned by ${admin}`)
          .setTimestamp()

          user.send({ embeds: [embed4] })
              setTimeout(function(){
                user.ban().catch(err => console.log(err)).then(() => {
                    message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed3] })
                    message.channel.bulkDelete(1);
                  }, 20000);
                })
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Turns out I was looking to see if I had the roles with `message.member` so i removed `message` from it and changed `member` to `user` and turned the roles into an array to clean up the code abit

Answer (score 1):

You are missing an `else` between

```
if(user.id === message.author.id){
  message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed5] })
}
```

and

```
 if (message.member
```

One way to make things like this more obvious is to auto-format your code.